# How to fix a while loop that repeats forever, even if the conditions are no longer met?

Tags: python, while-loop

I am creating a text-based game using python as part of a school assessment. I need to use a while loop that repeats until a variable equals 'west' or 'east'.

I have tried two methods and neither of them have worked.

These are the two methods I've used.

1:

```py
chamber = input("Enter 'east' or 'west' to choose a chamber: ")
while 'west' not in chamber.lower() or 'east' not in chamber.lower():
    chamber = input("Enter 'east' or 'west' to choose a chamber: ")
```

2:

```py
chamber = input("Enter 'east' or 'west' to choose a chamber: ")
while chamber.lower() != 'west' or 'east':
    chamber = input("Enter 'east' or 'west' to choose a chamber: ")
```

I expected it to loop until the variable 'chamber' is equal to either 'west' or 'east', but it keeps looping, regardless of what is entered.

Comment: ``while chamber.lower() != 'west' and chamber.lower() != 'east'``

Comment: `while chamber.lower not in {'east', 'west'}:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first snippet does not work because always one of the sub-conditions would be `True` and using `or` the whole condition is evaluated `True`

the second snippet is equivalent to `while chamber.lower() != 'west' or True`, so again the condition will always be evaluated `True`

use `while chamber.lower() not in ('west', 'east'):`

or:

```
while True:
    chamber = input("Enter 'east' or 'west' to choose a chamber: ")
    if chamber.lower() in ('west', 'east'):
        break
```

Note you can use set `{'west', 'east'}`, instead of tuple `('west', 'east')` which may bring performance if large number of elements. With just 2 elements there is no practical difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check whether the user input is exactly "east" or "west" I don't suppose they're going to put long string if they're prompted to enter something specific.

```
In [29]: def something():
    ...:     s = raw_input("enter ")
    ...:     while "east" != s and "west" != s:
    ...:         something()
    ...:         

In [30]: something()
enter east
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to evaluate each condition separately; Python is not AI.
Make this change to the second try:

```py
chamber = input("Enter 'east' or 'west' to choose a chamber: ")
while chamber.lower() != 'west' and chamber.lower() != 'east':
    chamber = input("Enter 'east' or 'west' to choose a chamber: ")
```

Your second snippet will always evaluate to `True` as even if you enter `west` the `chamber.lower() != 'east'` will be true.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this:

```
test = 1
chamber = input("Enter 'east' or 'west' to choose a chamber: ")
while test != 0:
    if chamber == 'east' or chamber == 'west':
        test = test - 1
    else:
        chambers = input("Enter 'east' or 'west' to choose a chamber: ")
```